# Como buscar por fecha en un timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo fechas almacenadas en timestamp de la forma:

```
1999-01-08 04:05:06
1999-01-24 13:22:29
```

Lo que quiero es realizar un consulta entre rangos de fechas es decir:

```
Inicio: 1999-01-09
Fin: 1999-01-12
```

Me devuelve los registros con fecha entre **1999-01-09** y **1999-01-11** es decir no toma en cuenta los días de la fecha fin, es decir obtengo:

```
1999-01-09
1999-01-10
1999-01-11
```

Pero también tengo

```
1999-01-12
```

Entonces lo que busco es obtener

```
1999-01-09
1999-01-10
1999-01-11
1999-01-12
```

la consulta que tengo es

```
select * from ingreso 
where fecha_hora between '1999-01-09' and '1999-01-12'
```

**¿Cómo podría obtener los resultados esperados?**

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema es que la fecha con dia 12 posee una hora mayor a 00:00:00 y al realizar la consulta como no colocas horas te coloca por defecto 00:00:00, deberias probar colocandola asi:

```
select * from ingreso  where fecha_hora between '1999-01-09 00:00:00'
and '1999-01-12 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Casi no uso `between` en las consultas con rango de fechas porque algunas veces he visto que no trae todos los registros que son o de forma exacta.

La forma como lo hago es usando los signos de **mayor igual y menor igual**  `>=` y `<=` para tu caso puede ser este ejemplo:

```
select * from ingreso 
where fecha_hora >='19990109' 
and fecha_hora <= '19990112'
```